# Flink cluster write data to mysql is lost

Tags: java, mysql, hive, apache-flink, flink-streaming

1. Problem
   Read the data in hive and write it to mysql. The data is missing.
   By using JdbcUpsertTableSink to transfer data, there are 90 pieces of data in hive and 70 pieces of data in mysql, but no data is lost in the local test. Flink does not have any abnormal information prompt.
2. Software version information:

- Flink version information: 1.11.1
- hive version information: 1.2.1
- mysql version information: 5.6

3. Below is my program

```java
public class MarketMonitorWriteMySQLJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ParameterToolFactory parameterToolFactory = new ParameterToolFactory();
        ParameterTool parameterTool = parameterToolFactory.createParameterTool();

        EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance()
                .useBlinkPlanner()
                .inBatchMode()
                .build();

        TableEnvironment tableEnv =
                TableEnvironment.create(settings);

        tableEnv.getConfig().setSqlDialect(SqlDialect.HIVE);


        HiveCatalog hiveCatalog = new HiveCatalog(CataLogEnum.NEW_BI.getCataLogName(),
                CataLogEnum.NEW_BI.getDbName(),
                parameterTool.get(FlinkProperEnum.FLINK_HIVE_CONF_DIR.key));

        tableEnv.registerCatalog(CataLogEnum.NEW_BI.getCataLogName(), hiveCatalog);

        tableEnv.useCatalog(CataLogEnum.NEW_BI.getCataLogName());



        ParameterTool fromArgs = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        String currentDay = DateConversionUtils.getCurrentDateToString();
        String currentDayNoBar = DateConversionUtils.getCurrentDateNoBarsToString();

        SQLBase marketMonitorSQL = new MarketMonitorSQL();
        String currentDateHour = String.valueOf(DateConversionUtils.getLastHour());
        String sql = "select * from new_bi.market_monitor_job where dt = '2020-11-25' and hs = 09";
        if (fromArgs.getNumberOfParameters() > 1) {
            String currentday = fromArgs.get("currentday");
            String currenthour = fromArgs.get("currenthour");

            String[] externalParams = new String[]{currentday, currenthour};
//            sql = String.format(sql, externalParams);
        } else {
            String[] dateArgs = {currentDay, currentDateHour};
//            sql = String.format(sql, dateArgs);
        }

        System.out.println(sql);

        JdbcOptions options = JdbcOptionsGenUtils.genJdbcOptions(
                parameterTool.get(FlinkProperEnum.FLINK_MYSQL_CUSTOM_DATASOURCE_NEWBI_URL.key),
                parameterTool.get(FlinkProperEnum.FLINK_MYSQL_CUSTOM_DATASOURCE_NEWBI_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME.key),
                parameterTool.get(FlinkProperEnum.FLINK_MYSQL_CUSTOM_DATASOURCE_NEWBI_USERNAME.key),
                parameterTool.get(FlinkProperEnum.FLINK_MYSQL_CUSTOM_DATASOURCE_NEWBI_PASSWORD.key),
                "market_monitor_job");


        TableSchema schema = TableSchema.builder()
                .fields(marketMonitorSQL.getSinkTableFields(), marketMonitorSQL.getSinkTableFieldTypes())
                .build();


        JdbcUpsertTableSink tableSink = JdbcUpsertTableSink.builder()
                .setOptions(options)
                .setTableSchema(schema)
//                .setFlushIntervalMills(1000)
                .setFlushMaxSize(100)
                .build();

        tableSink.setKeyFields(marketMonitorSQL.getSinkTableKeys());
        tableSink.setIsAppendOnly(false);

        tableEnv.registerTableSink("market_monitor_job_mysql_sink", tableSink);



        Table table = tableEnv.sqlQuery(sql);
        table.printSchema();

        StatementSet statement = tableEnv.createStatementSet();
        statement.addInsert("market_monitor_job_mysql_sink", table);
        statement.execute();
    }
}
```

The cluster does not provide any abnormal information, and I have no clue to deal with the problem! Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: Have you debugged the program?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I only have to print the result information of the query. The results of the online Flink cluster query are normal, but the data is lost when written to mysql. The local test can be written. Now debug does not know how to deal with it?